# Is there a way to tell a machine accesible via a gre tunnel to join multicast groups via pimd or smcroute?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, routing, udp, multicast

this has been stumping me for some time and would love any help on this.

So I am subscribed to a data vendor through an intermediary firm. The intermediary firm has physical connections to the data vendor, and has given me a tunnel that they say acts as a "pass through across our switch," to the data vendor.

Based on the multicast packets I am receiving across my tunnel, it looks like the intermediary company is running PIMv2 as we get the "Hello" Packet.

But it does not look like their machine is tunneling packets from the data vendor our way because they are not subscribed to the vendor's multicast groups. Is there a way to tell the intermediary machine that we tunnel with, to subscribe to the data vendor and route packets our way?

I've looked into pimd and smcroute, but it doesn't look like there is an answer. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server? The multicast group IP is 233.xxx.xxx.1 and source ip is: 23.xxx.xxx.150).

Here is our tunnel config:

```
tunnel    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr XX-XX-XX-XX-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.255.2  P-t-P:192.168.255.2  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1476  Metric:1
          RX packets:8887 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1425 errors:8 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:8
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:445245 (445.2 KB)  TX bytes:63884 (63.8 KB)
```

I have included a diagram below if it's helpful in understanding the problem. At this point, I'm lost on how to do this! 
[image: Network setup]